# Saving sql server xml result to disk

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2000

I have a C# application that calls a stored procedure that produces an xml result (using FOR XML Explicit) that I want to save to disk.  Doing some research I have found the following method:

```
var data = new DataSet();
XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
data.ReadXmlSchema(reader);
data.ReadXml(reader, XmlReadMode.Fragment);
data.WriteXml(filename);
```

However this outputs the following in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
  <NewDataSet />
```

I think this method might only work for XML Raw and XML Auto however I can look through the dataset's tables and see the data is there.

**UPDATE**: I was able to get it to work by not reading the XmlSchema and by not specifying the XmlReadMode.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why are you trying to do it with DataSet?  If you just want to work with the XML you should either use the XmlDocument or XDocument classes. DataSets don't play nice with some xml data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by not reading the XmlSchema and by not specifying the XmlReadMode.